# Some websites are not working in VPS proxy

Tags: twitter, proxy, youtube, vps, squid

I have just installed squid proxy on newly bought VPS, everything is working fine, except Youtube, Twitter, Instagram and Facebook. Anybody help me on this issue?

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: Hi, you should probably give more information: it might be the VPS provider, your country of origin, or the squid configuration (does it give add x-forwarded-for http header or similar ?). Most

Comment: My VPS is under "Cirrus Hosting" with dedicated IP, and I am using it from Pakistan for communicating with my international clients. Also all other websites are working fine from this proxy like; vimeo, dailymotion etc. just above mention sites are blocked and I don't know why.

Comment: The geo-IP base of those websites might have identified "Cirrus Hosting" as a VPS provider, and not a residential connection, thus filtering it to non-geo blocked content. It might also be bad colocation.

Last but not least, check the HTTP headers from your squid config.